# What is the difference between tf.group and tf.control_dependencies?

Tags: tensorflow

Aside from `tf.control_dependencies` being a context manager (i.e. used with Python `with`), what's the difference between `tf.group` and `tf.control_dependencies`?

When should which be used?

Is it that `tf.group` doesn't have any particular order of operations? I'd assume `tf.group([op_1, op_2, op_3])` executes ops in the list's order, but maybe that's not the case? The docstring doesn't specify a behaviour.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at the graphdef, the `c=tf.group(a, b)` produces the same graph as

```
with tf.control_dependencies([a, b]):
    c = tf.no_op()
```

There's no specific order in which ops will run, TensorFlow tries to execute operations as soon as it can (i.e. in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a few minor points to @Yaroslav-Bulatov answer.

As you can see from Yaroslav's answer:

- `tf.control_depenencies` creates no ops by itself, and adds dependencies to whatever ops your create inside its scope
- `tf.group` creates a single op (of type `NoOp`), adds dependencies to that op.

More importantly, if `tf.group` arguments belong to multiple devices, `tf.group` will insert an intermediate layer between its inputs and the node it returns. That layer will contain one node per device, so that the dependencies are organized by device. This could reduce the cross-device data flow.

So if your dependencies are on multiple devices, `tf.group` adds a (possibly critical) optimization.

On the other hand, `tf.control_dependencies` supports nesting: the inner context will add dependencies to the union of all the ops in the outer contexts.